# NavigationView widths

Tags: xcode, swiftui, navigationview

I'm using SwiftUI in XCode 12.4, and running into an issue where my NavigationView collapsed to a minimized state during it's second ever run, but I cannot seem to restore it in subsequent app runs.

The end result is this.
[image: See arrow pointing at edfe of NavigationView splitter]

The code is made up of three parts.

1. MainWindowView.
2. SidebarView
3. ContentView

These look like this:

1. MainWindowView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainWindowView: View {

    var body: some View {
        
        return ZStack {
            
            NavigationView {
                SideBarView()
                ContentView(text: "")
            }
            
        }
             
    }

}


struct MainWindowView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainWindowView()
    }
}
```

SidebarView looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SideBarView: View {
    
    private let names = ["Homer", "Marge", "Bart", "Lisa"]
    @State private var selection: String?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                    List(selection: $selection) {
                        Section(header: Text("The Simpsons")) {
                            ForEach(names, id: \.self) { name in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView(text: name)) {
                                    Text(name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
                    ContentView(text: "Make a selection")
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct SideBarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SideBarView()
    }
}
```

And finally, ContentView looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .frame(width:100)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(text: "Test")
    }
}
```

Now, I've tried adding frame widths to the sidebarview, and the navigationview and listview within it. I've tried adding widths to the text in the listview, too.  Nothing seems to fix the issue.

So, my questions are really two fold:

1. How do I set the width so I can see the text?
2. I can infer that the app is storing this width somewhere between app sessions. Where?

Many thanks,

Jason